# CSS offset path moving in reverse

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have an svg which I am trying to animate using CSS offset-path

```css
.c2 {
  transform-origin: 480px 566px;
  offset-rotate: -90deg;
  offset-path: path('M447.33 659.34 446.09 658.49 544.72 513.98 635.11 389.54 636.33 390.42 545.95 514.84 447.33 659.34z');
  animation: move 15s infinite alternate linear;
}

.c1 {
  transform-origin: 660px 394px;
  offset-rotate: -90deg;
  offset-path: path('M505.39 660.34 504.14 659.52 599.18 514.7 687.58 389.54 688.8 390.41 600.42 515.54 505.39 660.34z');
  animation: move 15s 2s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1400 980">
 <g id="cable2">
       <path d="M447.33 659.34 446.09 658.49 544.72 513.98 635.11 389.54 636.33 390.42 545.95 514.84 447.33 659.34z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="cable1">
      <path id="cabl1" d="M505.39 660.34 504.14 659.52 599.18 514.7 687.58 389.54 688.8 390.41 600.42 515.54 505.39 660.34z"/>
    </g>
    <g class="c2">
      <path d="M496.77,566.45h6a7,7,0,0,1,7,7v3.92h-13Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M480.76,577.39v-3.87a7,7,0,0,1,5.07-6.74v10.66Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M485.83,577.39V566.73a7.13,7.13,0,0,1,1.95-.28H497v10.94Z" fill="#294f5c"/>
      <path d="M509.83,600v3.92a7,7,0,0,1-7,7h-6V600Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M497,600v10.94h-9.17a7.13,7.13,0,0,1-1.95-.28V600Z" fill="#294f5c"/>
      <path d="M486,610.64a7,7,0,0,1-5.08-6.74V600H486Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <rect x="496.95" y="577.39" width="13.06" height="22.59" fill="#db4c40"/>
      <rect x="480.76" y="577.39" width="5.08" height="22.59" fill="#db4c40"/>
      <rect x="485.83" y="577.39" width="11.12" height="22.59" fill="#ff5a4a"/>
    </g>
    <g class="c1">
      <path d="M676.28,394.45h6a7,7,0,0,1,7,7v3.92h-13Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M660.27,405.39v-3.87a7,7,0,0,1,5.07-6.74v10.66Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M665.34,405.39V394.73a7.13,7.13,0,0,1,1.95-.28h9.17v10.94Z" fill="#294f5c"/>
      <path d="M689.34,428v3.92a7,7,0,0,1-7,7h-6V428Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <path d="M676.46,428v10.94h-9.17a7.13,7.13,0,0,1-1.95-.28V428Z" fill="#294f5c"/>
      <path d="M665.52,438.64a7,7,0,0,1-5.08-6.74V428h5.08Z" fill="#22414d"/>
      <rect x="676.46" y="405.39" width="13.06" height="22.59" fill="#db4c40"/>
      <rect x="660.27" y="405.39" width="5.08" height="22.59" fill="#db4c40"/>
      <rect x="665.34" y="405.39" width="11.12" height="22.59" fill="#ff5a4a"/>
    </g>
```

Now all I want is c1 and c2 to offset this path but from two different direction.

Is there any way to do this.
Is there any way to reverse the direction of one of the classes to make reverse?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: An option would be to add an `delay` to one of the animations so it starts halfway through - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GRpyXgK

Comment: Why don't you use [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion) for this?

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. That's all I needed.

Comment: @enxaneta I am trying to do it though CSS only and not SMIL. I am doing a storytelling and all the elements are animated through CSS. If I mix CSS and SMIL, browser will animate CSS first and SMIL later which will break the storytelling sequence.